# Thermoelectric EMF problem for low voltage measurement load cell

Tags: voltage-measurement, thermal, load-cell, low-voltage, emf

The resolution of a load cell is highly dependent on its capacity. That's because the higher the resolution and the higher the capacity, [the smaller the voltage change](https://www.ricelake.com/media/0xlllor2/wp_opcapacity.pdf). For example, many companies market a load cell with a capacity of 1 kg with a resolution of 0.1 grams, but there are no load cells on the market with a capacity of 100 kg with a resolution of 0.1 grams (if there is one, it would be very expensive).

Then, I found that measuring small voltages was difficult because of the influence of the [thermoelectric EMF](https://www.edn.com/troubleshoot-low-voltage-measurement-problems/), like Seebeck effect. We can see on that [website](https://www.edn.com/troubleshoot-low-voltage-measurement-problems/), the Seebeck Coefficient of Cu-Cu is ≤0.2 µV/°C. I think, the temperature difference in output circuit in the load cell is not much different, maybe less than 0.1°C because load cell use low current. So, for a temperature difference of 0.1°C, the noise voltage difference is roughly only about 0.02 µV.
Then, temperature changes take time, so the thermoelectric EMF noise also takes time to appear.

So what makes it so difficult to build a load cell with a large capacity and high resolution?

Comment: As you’ve noted, thermoelectric effects and measuring very small voltages are the problem. The load cell isn’t the problem - the instrumentation is. For 100kg cell and 0.1g resolution, that’s a dynamic range of 1000000:1 or around 20bits. Unfortunately noise swamps a significant amount of resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You can always drive the cell excitation with AC and get rid of the DC offsets.

I think the main limitations are mechanical- creep, hysteresis, maybe friction in some designs.

Comment: Can you explain about limitation in mechanical with resolution?

Comment: Have a look at a typical high quality [load cell datasheet](https://www.megatron.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Datenblaetter/Kraftsensoren/DS_KMB32_en.pdf). The various errors there characterized are independent of whatever electronics you stick on it. Eg. 0.5% creep (it will be time dependent with a decreasing magnitude of change with time).  As to the actual metallurgical causes of things like creep, that's another subject.

Comment: Of course, with care, one can make measurements of the voltage limited by noise and bandwidth and get resolutions of better than one part in 10^7 (eg. AD7177 at 5Hz- ~25 bits) but that extreme voltage resolution may not be very meaningful in terms of weight.